# How to parse larger json response with size 10MB in Android

Tags: android, json, web-services

I m developing one android app.
i m getting data from web service in the form of JSON which is about 10 MB in size.

I m getting error while using this JSON "OutOfMemoryError"

Comment: No, there is no method to parse json according to size. you need to compress the and uncompress the response.

Comment: at lease show some thing

Comment: I bet you are reading the whole response into memory before you process it. Try to interleave processing and reading.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [JSonReader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonReader.html)

Get your response as a stream for example

```
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8");

JSonreader reader = new JsonReader(isr);
```

Than you can parse by looping through the reader something like this:

```
reader.beginObject();
        while (reader.hasNext()) {
            String name = reader.nextName();

            if (name.equals("OBJECT")) {
                reader.beginArray();

                while (reader.hasNext()) {
                    Object obj= gson.fromJson(reader, Object.class);

                    objectList.add(obj);
                }
                reader.endArray();
            }
        }
        reader.endObject();
        reader.close();
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score -1):

if any outOfMemoryError IN ANDROID just Add this your manifest file,inside application tag.

```
<application
         android:largeHeap="true"
```

Comment: This is treating the symptom but not the real cause.

Comment: The question it self not clear right? i am just advice to him if any 'OutOfMemoryError' just use this solution.